# "Не бери у попа телицу, а у вдовы - девицу —"толкование поговорки

Tags: фразеология

Как понять поговорку: "не бери у попа телицу, а у вдовы - девицу"?

Answer (score 5):

"Не покупай у ямщика лошади, а у вдовы не бери дочери: у ямщика лошадь изломана, у вдовы дочь избалована," - В.И. Даль. "Пословицы русского народа"

Чем плохи коровы у священников не в курсе, но видимо тоже не слишком хорошо ухаживают за ними. Смысл пословицы - не делай глупостей.

Comment: Про глупость понятно. Это во всех вариантах.
А вот насчет изломанной лошади... Чушь. Имхо. 
Изломанная лошадь - это тягловая. Та, что с плугом ходит.  

Но за даля - плюсик. Это без вариантов, я поленился искать после первого похожего.

Comment: Ту, что с плугом ходит, хороший крестьянин холит и лелеет и перенапрягаться не даёт, иначе без хлеба останется.
А ямщик, заплати ему, и загнать лошадь может, так как не своя. Из-за казённости лошади, и следят за ней как понимаете похуже, чем за своей скотиною.

Answer (score 2):

Про вдову, думаю, имеется в виду, что девушка будет бесприданница, бедная. Насчет попа не знаю. Возможно, по аналогии, означает, что скотина у него запущенная, дохленькая.

Answer (score 2):

Дочь вдовы воспитывалась в неполноценной семье не знает взаимоотношений мужчины и женщины в семье. По статистике девочка выросшая без отца вероятнее всего будет плохой хранительницей семейного очага

Answer (score 1):

Могу предположить, что это самое дорогое, что у них есть. И забрать их было бы кощунством. Телица-жертвенное животное, ну а без девицы некому будет помогать по хозяйству. Возможно, поговорка уместна в случае, когда у кого-то отбирают что-то очень ценное, дорогое.

Comment: >Телица-жертвенное животное,
А ведь верно. Была у меня сходная мысль. Но смысл все равно не раскрывается, я от неё отказался.

Answer (score 1):

Интересная переделка поговорки... 
Даль приводит "Не купи у попа лошади, не бери у вдовы дочери". Но Даль тоже герешит против понимания. Каким боком тут поп - не очень понятно. Исходно, надо понимать, ***"У цыгана не купи лошади, у вдовы не бери дочери"***.
Последний вариант представляется самодостаточным.
Думаю, отношение цыгана к лошадям вполне сравнимо с тем, что испытывает вдова к дочери. Если и отдадут, то надуют.

Правда, может быть и "сопряженный" смысл. Ни лошади - цыгана, ни сироте-девице - мать ты не заменишь. Обе все равно мучиться будут.

Comment: про цыгана проще: лошадь краденая...

Comment: Тогда параллели с девицей нет

Comment: Ну может, параллель в том, что пожалеешь о своем выборе.
"Если и отдадут, то надуют" - как-то так, да. Но вдова надует не тем, что дочь плохая, а тем, что сама сядет на шею зятю, ведь ей больше не от кого ждать подмоги.

Comment: Все это очень интересно. Из всех ответов я бы выбрала следующее: "Не покупай у ямщика лошади, а у вдовы не бери дочери". Потому что у ямщика лошадь уже переработавшая свои возможности, а у вдовы дочь бедная, бесприданница.
Сколько всего нового открылось. Я про ямщика не слышала поговорки, но она вполне логична, а вот про попа, действительно, не понятно, какой может быть изъян у его лошади или у его телицы.

Comment: Да самый простой изъян, поп - плохой хозяин! А кроме того, извечная расейская недоверчивость к попам - смошенничает, подсунет то, что себе не гоже."На тебе, боже, что себе не гоже" - это про попов.
А приличную лошадь ямщик на извоз не возьмет, ей и в хозяйстве работы хватает."Лихачей" это, конечно, не касалось, там за стать и резвость совсем иные деньги платили.

Answer (score 1):

Телица, тёлка, она же *телушка* ж. (разг. и уменьш.-ласкат. к *тёлка*), молодая корова до трёх лет, не знавшая бычка. Она — ходячий капитал; и девица на выданье для вдовы — надежда на безбедную старость, тут вопрос выживания, и цена его высока. У попа, как правило, — самая большая семья и кормится она от прихода, то есть скудно и неровно, если и отдаст тёлку, то задрав цену донельзя; а вдова, коль скоро её с ребёнком не взял ни деверь, ни кто-то сторонний, а доходов не предвидится, лучше отправит своё чадо в люди, чем отдаст всякому — без выгоды для себя.

Так что смысл поговорки, думаю, такой: обаянием сделку не выправишь, приготовь сумму прописью.

Answer (score 0):

Поп не занимается хозяйством, это не его хлеб, лошадь не пригодна для работы. Или попу отдали лошадь, которая кому-то стала не нужна, типа попу сойдет. А вдова, не смогла сберечь своего мужа, такая хранительница, значит и дочку не научила, и у дочки муж проживет не долго, или другой вариант, муж погиб на фронте, и придется постоянно помогать теще (вдове), тянуть двух женщин.

Comment: Вообще-то телица - телка, нетелившаяся корова. При чем тут лошадь? Про вдову, которая "мужа не сберегла" - это уже околесина какая-то.